# Abort AJAX POST request after send but before response

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to post form data to Wufoo using AJAX.  I get an '**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**' error when I do it, but I realize that's in regards to the response from the server and not the form data being posted.  The form data actually makes it to Wufoo and gets posted.

Because I'm getting this error though, I can't do a "success" popup because the post request is, technically, failing.  I'm looking for a way to abort the post request after the data is sent but before a request is received.  Or, some way to recognize that the **outgoing** data was sent without problem and alert on that.

My simple little line of code:

```
submitForm = $.post("https://mansueto.wufoo.com/forms/w1yxemaa06vtv7p/#public", $('#form65').serialize());
```

Answer (score 0):

> The form data actually makes it to Wufoo and gets posted.

If you are certain that the data is received by server, you could use [`.always()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always) to perform tasks that would normally be performed at `.done()`

```
$.post(url, $('#form65').serialize())
.always(function() {
  // do stuff
})
```